# BesselJ function on negative real numbers

Tags: special-functions

I have evaluated Bessel$J_v(x)$ with some real $v$ and negative real $x$ in MATHEMATICA. I cannot understand how the result is complex (non-real). I look at the series definition of BesselJ and I cannot see where an imaginary number comes in.
What am I missing?

Comment: Which values of $\nu$ were considered?

Comment: Several values. For example, 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex values are a consequence of the complex power function. Look at the power series of $J_{\nu}$ with the term in front of the sum:
$$J_\nu(x) = (\tfrac{1}{2}x)^{\nu} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k
\frac{(\tfrac{1}{4}x^2)^k}{k!\Gamma(\nu+k+1)!}\;,$$
If you take e.g. $x=-2$ and $\nu=2.2$ it has the value
$$(-2)^{2.2}\approx3.7172660+2.7007518i$$
The situation is the same for $I_{\nu}$ because these functions also have the factor $(\tfrac{1}{2}x)^{\nu}.$